# experiences among or experiences from/in?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence:
"His work is often inspired by travel experiences among other cultures"
grammatically correct?

It sounds a bit odd to me. Would "experiences from" be better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello LeFunk.  You have not indicated the source for this quote.  Did you write it yourself?  If not please tell us who did write it, and if possible link to the source.  Can you provide more context.  At least enough so we know who "His" refers to.

Comment: I don't think the context matters here at  all, the answer does not depend on context.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct, and the meaning is clear, but it is somewhat unnatural.

Prefer to say:  "**His work has often been inspired by his experience traveling among other cultures.**"

(It also works in present simple tense: "**His work is often inspired by his experience traveling among other cultures.**, but if you are about to give examples of his past work, use the present perfect as in the first example above.)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of options here

> His work is often inspired by travel experiences among other cultures

As you state this does not quite ring true. I think I might have used *in* or *within* instead of *among*. Your suggestion of *from* is not, as far as I can see, an improvement on *among*.

I would almost be inclined to re-write the whole thing as

> His work is often inspired by the other cultures he experienced while travelling.

which sounds much neater to me although I would find it hard to explain just exactly why.

Comment: Thank you - can "the" be omitted?
His work is often inspired by other cultures he experienced while travelling.

Comment: Yes, you could omit it. I think I would keep it but it is a matter of style rather than grammar.

Comment: "His work is often inspired by the other cultures he **experiences** while traveling."

Comment: (Or:  "His work is often inspired by the other cultures he **has experienced** while traveling.")

Answer (score 0):

But isn't it strange altogether to say ***cultures*** in this structure? I mean, you travel *in countries*, not *among cultures*. As mdewey spotted it, *cultures* is rather connected to *experience* than to travelling. I am thinking of expressing it like this:

> His work is often inspired ***by his travels in other countries, through which he experienced other cultures.***

I know, this is a rather complicated sentence, so maybe we can simplify it in this way:

> His work is often inspired ***by his experience in other cultures, which he acquired while travelling.***

Comment: "you travel in countries, not among cultures"  seems like a strange rule to impose.  I don't have to change my country to have a cultural experience, and I also don't necessarily need to visit a different culture if I leave my country.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is perfectly fine as is, though a bit old fashioned.

If you change the sentence to "His work is often inspired by travel experiences from other cultures" the meaning would be changed to it's the other cultures doing the traveling, and their experiences is then what he draws inspiration from. As opposed to the original sentence where he does the travelling, and draws insiration from those experiences.

It would be possible to make the experiences implied without changing the meaning "His work is often inspired by travelling among other cultures". Since it should be common knowledge it's not the actual travelling (putting one foot infront of the other) that you draw inspiration from.

If you change travel experiences to only experiences you open up to the possibility that he lived there for a while, were now the sentence states explicitly he went on a vacation, saw the sites, and then went home.

If you change among to within, it shifts the meaning to experiences for the members of the cultures, rather than his own experiences as an outsider walking amongst them.